# PHP: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *") doesn't work

Tags: php

I am playing around with the PHP, use ajax send request to `0.0.0.0/ajax.php`, but the actual url now is `localhost`, so it turned out an javascript error because of the **same origin policy**.

The `ajax.php`:

```
session_start();

if ( $_SESSION['http_origin'] ) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}

// below is some code handle ajax request
```

I know header function doesn't work after any output, so the above code is at top of source file. `$_SESSION['http_origin']` is already set to `TRUE`, if put `echo "ok";` under the `header` in the if statement, it will output "ok".

BUT, when i use ajax request this page, it will show me an error which is due to **same origin policy**, and if I replace the `$_SESSION['http_origin']` with `1`, it will work fine.

So, did I missing something?

Comment: There is no explanation for the behaviour you describe. So we have to assume that the behaviour depends on some other issue you do _not_ describe here.

Comment: @arkascha Here are the whole code: https://github.com/Dryforest/php-sameoriginpolicy if you are interested.

Comment: One remark on your code: you wrote comment "fix the silly same origin policy"... Actually that policy evaluation makes totally sense. The fact that you have problems using (controlling) it does not mean it is silly. About your problem: I suggest you use your browsers development console to check what policy headers are actually received and evaluated.

Comment: @arkascha well, i just copy it from the source code of `php.net` website. I have no opinion on this comment. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Never copy code and use it without questioning its content ;-) So what does the console tell you?

Comment: @arkascha interesting, now it just works ...

Comment: As said: some other issue. Happens, don't worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

It's because session can not shared on different domains. If I visit 0.0.0.0, it outputs "ok", but if I visit localhost, it doesn't.

my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

- remove blank space on starting of `<?php` code
- also try to use ob_start(); on top after starting `<?php`

Comment: Low quality answer, be more clear

Comment: sorry dude, check now yaar

Answer (score 0):

I guess, `$_SESSION['http_origin']`  should be `$_SERVER['http_origin']` and when you put 1 instead of `$_SESSION['http_origin']` its always true so it applies.